# startDate, endDate, and adding text to label in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, healthkit

So I am having a few bugs and errors in my ViewController code in my app. First, in my line:

```
let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate,endDate: endDate ,options: .None)
```

I get the following error: `use of unresolved identifier 'endDate'`

This is weird. Is it because I have not made them into NSDate objects? How would I go about doing that?

As for my second question, it is not exactly a bug, I simply do not know how to do something. I have connected my label from the storyboard into my view controller. I want to get the data I collect to simply print onto the screen in the label. I know how to do this in most situations but I am lost as to how I can do this within my current configuration. I don't want the user to press a button or anything, I just want it to automatically display by default...Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

I have included all my code below:

```
import UIKit
import HealthKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var displayData: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // create store

        let healthStore = HKHealthStore()

        // create an object type to request an authorization for a specific category, here is SleepAnalysis

        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryTypeForIdentifier(HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis) {

            let setType = Set<HKSampleType>(arrayLiteral: sleepType)
            healthStore.requestAuthorizationToShareTypes(setType, readTypes: setType, completion: { (success, error) -> Void in
                // here is your code
            })
        }

        if let sleepType = HKObjectType.categoryTypeForIdentifier(HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis) {

            // we create a predicate to filter our data
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamplesWithStartDate(startDate,endDate: endDate ,options: .None)

            // I had a sortDescriptor to get the recent data first

            let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: false)

            // we create our query with a block completion to execute

            let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: sleepType, predicate: predicate, limit: 30, sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, tmpResult, error) -> Void in
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`endDate` is undefined - you have not actually created a variable that represents `endDate` - thus the compiler is telling you that.  And, also, `startDate` is also undefined, even though the compiler hasn't told you that yet.  In the least, you need to create `NSDate`s.

```
let startDate = NSDate()
let endDate = NSDate()
```

More specifically, you'll need to create them in the range for which you want to query.

Regarding showing the data by default, simply set the `UILabel`'s text in `viewDidLoad`.  I'm assuming that you want to set this text in response to the HealthKit query?  If so, you can still do that in `viewDidLoad`

So, to use your query, it needs to be provided to `executeQuery` on `healthStore`   Here's some code that you could use with what you posted:

```
healthStore.executeQuery(HKSampleQuery(
    sampleType: sleepType,
    predicate: predicate,
    limit: 30,
    sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor],
    resultsHandler: { (query: HKSampleQuery!, results: [AnyObject]!, err: NSError?) -> Void in
        if err != nil {
            // ERROR Occurred, handled it
            println(err)
            return
        }
        var labelText = ""
        for result in results as [HKQuantitySample]! {
            // SUCCESS, use results here
            labelText += result
        }
        displayData.text = labelText
    }
))
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome answer!!! Where would I implement this code? I tried adding it directly after my second if statement but Xcode threw me errors saying that sleepType, predicate and sortDescriptor used unresolved identifiers. I'm pretty sure this is because the location I put the code is out of scope, but I'm not sure where else I would put it.

Comment: Replace the "let query..." line with that code, and it should work.  A quick glance seems to indicate that all the variables are within scope.